Golden Gate Replicate to Mirrored Database in Microsoft Fabric - Azure Identity Error
Golden Gate for Distributed Applications and Analytics v23.6
OS: oracle linux 8
SDK Dependencies:

onelake v12.20.0
hadoop v3.4.0
parquet v1.12.0

Issue
I'm trying to replicate a sample trail file from <OGG_HOME>/opt/AdapterExamples/trail into a Mirrored Database in a Microsoft Fabrics workspace. When I start the replicat process, I encounter the following error:
Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call for scopes [https://storage.azure.com/.default]: java.io.UncheckedIOException: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
I checked credentials using the azure-identity (1.10.0) and azure-storage-file-datalake (12.8.0) libraries in a Python script, and it was successful in listing files in a Fabrics Lakehouse.
I have provided the properties file and the full error from the Replicat Report file below:

Properties File for Replicat test1
Configuration to load GoldenGate trail operation records into a Mirrored Database in Microsoft Fabric:
gg.target=fabric_mirrored_database
#TODO: Edit the Fabric workspace name.
gg.eventhandler.onelake.workspace=fabric
#TODO: Edit the Fabric mirror name.
gg.eventhandler.onelake.mirror=testfabricdb
#TODO: Edit the tenant ID of the application.
gg.eventhandler.onelake.tenantId=<tenant id>
#TODO: Edit the client ID of the application.
gg.eventhandler.onelake.clientId=<client id>
#TODO: Edit the client secret for the authentication.
gg.eventhandler.onelake.clientSecret=<secret>
#TODO: Edit the classpath to include Hadoop, Parquet, and Azure DataLake SDK dependencies.
gg.classpath=/u01/app/oracle/product/ogg/opt/DependencyDownloader/dependencies/hadoop_3.4.0/:/u01/app/oracle/product/ogg/opt/DependencyDownloader/dependencies/parquet_1.12.3/:/u01/app/oracle/product/ogg/opt/DependencyDownloader/dependencies/onelake/*
#TODO: Edit the proxy configuration.
#jvm.bootoptions=-Dhttps.proxyHost=some-proxy-address.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true

Full Error message sourcing from Replicat Report file:
propertiesERROR 2024-12-25 11:24:48.000991 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5] - {"az.sdk.message":"Retry attempts have been exhausted.","exception":"io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException","tryCount":3}
=ERROR 2024-12-25 11:24:48.000991 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5] - io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
=ERROR 2024-12-25 11:24:48.000992 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5] - Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call for scopes [https://storage.azure.com/.default]: java.io.UncheckedIOException: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
=ERROR 2024-12-25 11:24:48.000992 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5] - {"az.sdk.message":"Failed to acquire a new access token.","exception":"java.io.UncheckedIOException: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException"}
=ERROR 2024-12-25 11:24:48.000996 [TaskEngine_5(FileFinalizeTask)] - ONELAKE-00053 Error occurred while uploading a file to Microsoft Fabric OneLake. Inspect the replicat handler log file and the replicat report file for further troubleshooting. Contact Oracle support if you cannot resolve the error.

I followed instructions from: https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/post/how-to-replicate-to-mirrored-database-in-microsoft-fabric-using-goldengate

To be able to authenticate to Fabric Mirrored DB api, Azure App Registration platform has to be Web.
I create a new app with Web Platform type and Replicat works.
Below you can see the App registration page: 
